# Angular 7 show/hide mat-table rows definition dynamically

Tags: angular, angular-material, xlsx

I'm trying to export my `mat-table` data to Excel using `xlsx`. Working sample at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6uxpdq):

Before exporting I'd like to hide expandable rows of the table, because it doesn't look good in excel. In my local sample I also have one more row in table definition that contain filter inputs for each column, which I'd also like to hide.

I tried to manage row visibility with variable `exportActive`, but when changed to `true` the rows do not hide dynamically.

I'd appreciate any help.